# Is it possible to get 3D objects with the coords they have on the screen (XNA)?

Tags: c#, 3d, xna

I'm currently trying to create a game were you can select units by "boxing them" (click then drag to create a box of selection). However, the units are coded in 3D and have 3D coords, and the selection rectangle is in 2D on my screen.

Now I'm trying to convert 3D coords to 2D coords on my camera view, knowing : coords of the 3D item, coords of my camera, and where it is looking at. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use The Viewport.Unproject() method to achieve that.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.viewport.unproject.aspx

Use the model position you want to select as the *source* Vector3 and your camera's *View* and *Projection* for parameters (you can use Matrix.Identity for the *World* matrix).